# Best way to handle a REST URI that needs to have an emailId in path parameter

Tags: rest, encoding, microservices, uri

I have a new API endpoint that has a base64 encoded path parameter. It looks like this:

```
/user/save/:userEmail
```

What's the best way to handle the path parameter here?
I think the options are URLencoding or Base64 encoding. Which of these 2 work better? Also, any other options that I haven't considered?

Answer (score 0):

Base64 encoding introduces an extra step, and as far as I am aware we don't have a standardized mechanism for describing that.

So my recommendation would be to use [URI templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570), and side step the base64 concern completely.  You can reasonably expect clients to find libraries that provide [pct-encoded](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A) values where necessary.